ASP.NET Web-API with multiple dots in project-name not starting on macOS
I got a little API-project implemented with .NET 8.
The name of the project looks like this:
My.Fancy.Name.Space.Service.csproj

The Project works perfectly fine on my Windows-machine. Even in containers with the ASP.NET Docker-Images everything is fine.
But whenever I try to start this project on macOs the following error appears:

Process finished with exit code 137.

It does not matter if I start the project with Rider, Visual Studio or via command-line(dotnet run). The error remains the same.
It turns out, that if I rename my project from My.Fancy.Name.Space.Service.csproj to Service.csproj everything works just fine. While searching for a fix, it seems like this is the only way to avoid the issue.
The problem is by doing that I'm violating some namespace conventions.
Is there any workaround to avoid this issue?

Not sure why your question was down-voted. Seems to be well explained to me. Some people are just born negative I guess. Given that no comment to explain the down-vote was made.

Are you running the project using Docker on macOS as well?
As exit code 137 might indicate that your Docker doesn't have enough RAM. Maybe this is a path to investigate?

@kristofke No im running it on the machine itself. If I use Docker it works
